# How can I configure Ninject to inject my DbContext for use with ASP.NET Identity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I'd like to use Ninject to inject my DbContext ASP.NET Identity Framework.

At the moment I have the following line in my `web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="OwinTest.Identity.OwinStart, OwinTest.Identity" />
</appSettings>
```

This causes the `Configuration()` method on class `OwinStart` in my OwinTest.Identity project to be called.

Here's my OwinStart class:

```
public class OwinStart
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<IMyContext>(this.GetDbContext);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login")
                });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an instance of the DbContext for OWIN
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IMyContext GetDbContext()
        {
            // Create dbcontext instance
            return new MyContext();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I create an instance of my `DbContext` using the `new` keyword, when I really want to be making use of Ninject to inject my DbContext in.

Is it possible for me to wire up Ninject to inject my database context in within OWIN?

Comment: Not Ninject discussion, but DI registrations for Identity: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

Comment: @trailmax Thanks, I happened to stumble upon that article before writing this question.  That example still relies on a static method that `new`s up a DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the best you can do here is:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyContext>();
```

**Update**

After discussion the issue in chat we established that:

- Owin app is self-hosted and does not reference System.Web
- It is separate from the MVC application that used Ninject.MVC

This basically means that DI container can't be shared between the two. The [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of an application should be as close to the starting point as possible, which, for OWIN, means the start up method.

In this particular use case you are not gaining anything from having ninject in this application as you are instantiating your DbContext right next to your composition root.

The article trailmax linked says:

> Also this does not use our Unity container, this uses Owin for object resolution. We don’t want to mix Owin registrations with Unity registrations for many reasons (the biggest reason is lack of lifetime management between 2 containers).

So the main advantage of using a DI container with owin would be if you are already using it for the rest of the application, and want owin and the rest of the application share the registrations. That's not your case.

Comment: `DependencyResolver` is in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace... OWIN is designed to work without any references to `System.Web`.

Comment: If you are not using MVC, I don't understand what your problem is. You are right at the composition root!

Comment: Do you mean the problem with newing up a DbContext without using an IoC?

Comment: Let me rephrase. Where is the composition root in your application?

Comment: My project that is making use of ASP.NET Identity Framework is indeed an MVC application, but the OWIN stuff hosts itself independently of the MVC project or the System.Web pipeline.  So for the purposes of OWIN, I guess that the entry point (if that's what you mean by composition root :S) is the `OwinStart` class `Configuration` method?

Comment: I am indeed.  That's where my problems arise, I don't have access to just use the kernel that exists in my MVC project from the OWIN context... as far as I'm aware?

Comment: Is Owin part and MVC part the same application, or are they two different applications? (You are talking about self-hosting, which apparently is not possible with MVC)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76033/discussion-between-zespri-and-coulton).

Comment: Yeah, the ASP.NET Identity stuff is self hosted, not MVC itself, so it's independent of the MVC project.